# Opposite of "unwrappable"

Tags: word-request, antonyms

So, if we want to say that something is capable of being unwrapped, we could say, that it's *unwrappable*.

How do we say with one word that something is **not** capable of being unwrapped? *Ununwrappable* doesn't yield many search results.

Comment: Actually, my first thought with "unwrappable" is something that can't be wrapped. Which doesn't really make sense, we would just say "too big to wrap" instead.

Answer (score 1):

"Unwrapping" is the process of removing the wrapping. There is no such word as "un-unwrappable", although I suppose it could be used in a humorous way. English speakers would recognise the intended meaning even though it is not a real word.

If you are seriously looking for a word for something that is not *meant* to be unwrapped, I would suggest "*sealed*", or "*impenetrable*". You might even be able to use "*unopenable*", as some people use "open" interchangeably with "unwrap" (eg "opening presents")

If something is meant to be unwrapped, but it is just *difficult*, then it is just "*difficult to unwrap*", "*well wrapped*", or perhaps "*tightly wrapped*".

Comment: I might write 'non-unwrappable', but I would be more inclined to stop and think some more about what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

*Unwrappable* is a terrible word, like *irregardless* or *inflammable*.  Avoid it.

Something that can be unwrapped has a wrapper and has been wrapped at some point in the past.  So you can say it is *wrapped*.

If something has been wrapped and the wrapper can't be removed, it's *sealed*.

A wrapper is a cover, and something that doesn't have a cover is *uncovered*, or *unsealed*.  You can also say *unwrapped* - but if this is a business setting and you want to communicate status quickly, using two words that don't sound the same will get the meaning communicated more reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is no single word that applies. This is one of those cases. While you can come up with words that could be considered somewhat synonymous, the easiest method of communicating the idea is to simply say the following:

> It is ***not unwrappable***.

In fact, that's the purpose of the word [*not*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/not):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** —used as a function word to make negative a group of words or a word

While *un* acts as a prefix to form a closed or hyphenated negation of a word, *not* is used for the same purpose (forming an open negation) when *un* is inappropriate.